# Merge text files with 1st column and difference in output file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, files, join

File 1: (`text1.txt`)

```
Row_Added_Ts    Count   
01/01/14        2022448     
02/01/14        8345155   
03/01/14        8663852  
04/01/14        6785739  
05/01/14        5279913
```

File 2: (`text2.txt`)

```
Row_Added_Ts    Count  
01/01/14    211      
02/01/14    1598    
03/01/14    1710    
05/01/14    5279913  
06/01/14    7953261
```

Output File:

```
Row_Added_Ts    Count       Row_Added_Ts    Count   Difference  
01/01/14        2022448     01/01/14    211         2022237  
02/01/14        8345155     02/01/14    1598        8343557  
03/01/14        8663852     03/01/14    1710        8662142  
04/01/14        6785739     04/01/14    0           6785739  
05/01/14        5279913     05/01/14    5279913     0  
06/01/14        0           06/01/14    7953261     -7951831
```

The requirement is to combine 2 files and fill the rows with `0` where there is no match. Also do the difference of Count in the final Output File.

I had tried to combine with `join` and `awk` commands, but didn't get the desired output.

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 text1.txt text2.txt  

awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "/t"}
NR == FNR {f[$1] = $0 next}
  {print f[$1]   $0}' text2.txt text1.txt
```

Also `join` with `sort` is not working in `sh`, `ksh` or `bash`.

Comment: Are the contents in the source files tab separated?

Comment: It can be Tab or Comma as Im creating those files.

Comment: @Chaos - Issue resolved.. It was due to the headers present in the file. Once i removed the headers the following command worked fine.. `join -t$'\t' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,0,2.2 text1.txt text2.txt | awk 'OFS="\t"{$5=$2-$4}1'`

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` and `awk` together:

```
join -t $'\t' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,0,2.2 file1 file2 | \
  awk 'OFS="\t"{$5=$2-$4}NR==1{$5="Difference"}1'
```

Where:

- `-t` sets the input and output delimiter
- `-j` defines the join field in both files
- `-a` forces join to print unpairable lines from both files
- `-e` specifies how to fill the empty fields
- and `-o` is the output format
- `awk` first sets the output field separator `OFS` to tab
- the 5th field `$5` is calculated from the 2nd and 4th
- and if it's the first line in the file, format the 5th field as header

Comment: Thank you, It works like a charm. Except that, it doesnt display Count from file 1. It displays Date from file1, Date from File2 and Count from File 2.

Comment: @BadrinarayanaVengavasi can you post the output of the command without the awk part? And please post the output of `join --version` and `awk -W version`?

Comment: @BadrinarayanaVengavasi your file `text1.txt` is not tab delimited, while the second file `text2.txt` is tab delimited. This confuses join. Can you run the following command on text1.txt: `sed -i.bak -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" text1.txt`

Comment: I tried the other way round and ran with `text2.txt text1.txt` instead of `text1.txt text2.txt` in the command you gave. Im getting the counts from `text1.txt1` and 0 from `text2.txt`. Also ran the command and got the following output: 
`bash-4.2$ sed -i.bak -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" text1.txt`
`sed: Not a recognized flag: i`

Comment: I tried modified the file to , delimited and i get the same output as mentioned in the below answer.

Comment: The issue was with `join -t $'\t'`. Although I could not change it in tab delmited, I have modified the file to Comma Delimited and gave this command: `join -t"," -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,0,2.2 text3.txt text4.txt | awk 'OFS=","{$5=$2-$4}NR==1{$5="Difference"}1'`
Join part works fine.. but the awk part adds 4 commas extra after column 4.

Comment: @BadrinarayanaVengavasi The easiest would be if you could change the dlimiter to space, then you can remove `-t $'\t'`